# sqlite visual studio 2015

Tags: c, visual-studio, sqlite, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to make a program using sqlite and visual studio. I've added `sqlite3.def, sqlite3.c, sqlite3.h, sqlite3.dll` files to the project directory. I've also added `THREADSAFE` and `SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA` in the project settings to the preprocessor definitions and sqlite3.def in `Linker -> Input -> Module definition file`. I'm trying to compile the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sqlite3.h"


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    sqlite3* db;
    char* zErr;
    int rc;
    char* sql;

    rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);

    if (rc)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        exit(1);
    }

    sql = "create table episodes( id integer primary key,"
          "                       name text, cid int)";

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, &zErr);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (zErr != NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErr);
            sqlite3_free(zErr);
        }
    }

    sql = "insert into episodes (name,id) values ('Cinnamon Babka2',1)";
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, &zErr);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (zErr != NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErr);
            sqlite3_free(zErr);
        }
    }

    sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
}
```

And I get a whole bunch of errors, here are some of them:

```
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol sqlite3_aggregate_context
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol sqlite3_backup_finish
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol sqlite3_backup_pagecount
```

My question is how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: C is not C++ si not C! Don't add tags for unrelated languages. This looks like C, but if you compile with a C++ compiler **change** the tag to C++.

Answer (score 1):

There are two projects involved in this - the sqlite3.dll and the code you are writing.

### main application

This does not build the sqlite3 code, but does require the header file "sqlite3.h", and access to the library file which defines the functions in `sqlite3.dll` and the .dll to get them from.

Don't add the .def (that describes what is being exported).
Don't add the .c file.

- In the linker settings.
- In General

Add Additional Library Directories, the directory containing `sqlite3.lib`
 - In the linker settings.
 - In Input
Add sqlite3.lib to the Additional Dependencies.

### Build a DLL with exports (sqlite3.dll)

To build a DLL with exports, you need.

1. A description of the files being exported (sqlite3.def)
2. Files to compile (sqlite3.c)

This creates a .lib file (description of the exports) and a .dll (implementation of the code).

### Troubleshooting

The  [Microsoft : Windows DDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx)  includes an application called depends.exe.  This can be used to view a `.DLL` or `.EXE` imports and exports.  This helps you identify if the DLL was correctly built.

The linker option /VERBOSE:LIB ([MSDN : /Verbose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdsk6as6.aspx) ) shows which files the linker is searching for import definitions.